# Tcl module: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, linux, architecture, swig

I am running the test tcl module from the Swig tutorial site: http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html.

However, when I enter: `gcc -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.so` into the command line, it returns:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TclFreeObj", referenced from:
      __wrap_My_variable_get in example_wrap.o
      __wrap_My_variable_set in example_wrap.o
    .
    . 
    .

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions on what the issue may be?

Comment: Your `gcc` is not `gcc`!

Comment: It looks like you need to link in at least one external library -- probably libtcl.  Try adding the option `-ltcl` to the end of your compilation command.